# How can I send APNS PushSharp send notification. It's working from localhost in asp.net but fail when we host API in Windows server

Tags: c#, ios, asp.net-web-api, xamarin.ios, pushsharp

I have implemented APNS PushSharp in asp.net web api using C# for Xamarin.ios native app. When we run api in localhost its send notification to iOS devices for both development and distribution certificate. But when we host api in IIS and call service, its fail to send notification. We did’t identify issue..can you please guide me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have solved this issue by setting folder permission correctly on windows server.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and I solved it by changing the identity of the application pool on which my website was running